# create a bootable usb to automatic repair windows xp system32 files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, filesystem-corruption

Is it possible to create a script/live distro that replaces some system32 files?

To explain it a bit more in details:

There is a company that has multiple computers (think in 100/1000's) and they all are missing the same system32 files since the company's software removed it.

The systems are distributed all over the world and are managed by "normal" people who don't have any knowledge about computers.

I want to create a usb stick that i can mail to all those people which contains a script that executes when you boot the usb. this script should replace the missing system32 files without any user input

is this possible, and if so how could i manage this?

Comment: Have you confirmed if you simply replace the file that the problem is solved?

Comment: Yes i have, if the files are replaced the system is working correctly again

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [UBCD4Win](http://www.ubcd4win.com/) or [Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd):

- *UBCD4Win* is completely configurable, but you will need an external program to convert the ISO CD image to bootable USB disc format;
- *Hiren's Boot CD* is available as a bootable USB, but I have not investigated if it can be configured for your purposes: see [Hiren from USB Flash](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk).

Comment: Since writing this answer, the domain for UBCD4WIN (which has not been updated for some time, but still is a useful repair disc) has been released, though I daresay there will be other sites where it is held. I have also been made aware of [Hiren's CD 2 Bootable USB](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hirenscd2bootableusb/), which looks like a simpler way to create a bootable USB from Hiren's Boot CD, but which I have not tried.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a company network, and users are 'normal users' as you refer to them, not power users, then a typical way to resolve this would be to issue an update through the company network and deploy new versions of files onto all machines remotely. In the worst case this can be done manually by a system administrator, who would open a remote connection session and do all necessary changes.

Making changes and replacing system files should *never* be trusted to regular users. Trying to automate the process by means of bootable USB's, batch files etc is not an acceptable solution and will highly likely result into even more serious problems. And at the end of the day 'normal users' as you call them will never be responsible for any consequences.

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to distribute the files over an existing network since the (some) computers don't boot anymore. and with "normal" users i mean users that do not have any knowledge about computers in general exempt for the software they use